# ProgressBar not animated

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to show a top progress bar. The progress bar appears, **but** it's not animated.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/departureProgressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-6dp" />
```

My gradle contains :

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
```

My device has at least Android 5.0

Any ideas ?

**EDIT :**

http://www.materialdoc.com/linear-progress/

> ProgressBar is not displayed in material style on pre Lollipop devices.

**EDIT 2 :**

My device is 5.1.1, so it's must be working...

Comment: for test case add `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal`

Comment: Are you able to see progressbar? What is happening?

Comment: remove `android:layout_marginTop`

Comment: yes the progress bar is showing, but not animating

Comment: `android:indeterminateOnly="true"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I tried, but not working

Comment: @Xero which device?

Comment: Sony Xperia I think, on Android 5.1.1

Comment: @Xero solve this yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya unfortunatly no

Comment: @Xero okay .did you try with another any library ?

Comment: I had similar issue which got solved then I changed the dialog theme style to @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported for pre-lollipop but you can use this alternative [library](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar).

Comment: I can show the progress bar. I tried, but it's still not animating.

Comment: check the gradle mentioned above

Comment: I have     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

Comment: sorry check the post http://www.materialdoc.com/linear-progress/ bottom part , its not supported

Comment: use this library for pre lollipop https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will tried this later if no other solution is proposed, and upvote your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121228/discussion-between-don-and-xero).

Answer (score 0):

Add like this in respective layout.

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Implement it in your main activity and fill the necessary codes for visibility. By default it will be visible.